# How to use frontmatter description as blog preview instead of using truncate

Tags: docusaurus

I'm wondering if it would be possible to use description from blog frontmatter as the blog preview on blog landing page.

```
---
slug: disk-usage
title: "How to monitor the disk usage on your infrastructure"
description: "The most important part of disk usage monitoring is to check the utilization of each filesystem and each mount point which can reveal existing or impending issues with the storage space on your infrastructure."
image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/88642300/197860415-bdff658c-7dd3-4a9e-b39a-fbddd3b44d57.png
tags: [how-to,infrastructure-monitoring]
keywords: [how-to,infrastructure-monitoring]
authors: satya
---

<!--truncate-->

Disk usage (DU) refers to the portion or percentage of computer storage that is currently in use. It contrasts with disk space or capacity, 
...
```

So use the `description` from above as the preview text in here:

[image: example of blog list landing page]

I tried to swizzle a few things but could not quite figure out what specifically to try play around with.